# can't delete object due to foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to do a simple `user.destroy` but running into the following error:

> ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_5373344100" on table "identities"
>   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "identities".

Here is my migration for Identities

```
class CreateIdentities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :identities do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :provider
      t.string :uid

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my user and identity model:

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :uid, :provider
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid, :scope => :provider

  def self.find_for_oauth(auth)
    find_or_create_by(uid: auth.uid, provider: auth.provider)
  end
end
```

and user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX = 'ricky@writeit.com'
  TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX = /\ricky@writeit.com/

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  validates_format_of :email, :without => TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX, on: :update
...

end
```

I'm new to foreign keys and references, so I'm not sure at all how to fix this.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You would need to remove the Identity that references the user first.  Then you can delete the user..  By default the foreign key is doing a `restrict` so you cannot delete the user if anything references to it.

if you would like use Rails to handle destroying the identity you can do

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :identities,  dependent: :destroy 

  ......

 end
```

Which would cause Rails to destroy all the dependent records.

But as you are using Foreign keys, you can adjust your migration to set cascade deletes

```
 add_foreign_key :identities, :users, on_delete: :cascade
```

Assuming rails 4.2 which has native support

Comment: Awesome! But just a small thing, he need to remove the foreign key first then add it again with on_delete: :cascade

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution is to simply cascade-delete the records in the associated table, which can be done through active record, like so:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :identities, dependent: :destroy

  # rest of user class
end
```

Check out the [documentation pertaining to `has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options) for more info.