# Issue in rake db:load command while switching to mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a project in Rails 4,previously i was using sqlite3 as a database,i switched to mysql database and changed all its configuration in database.yml file.I also got all my migrations successful while running rake db:migrate.

```html
i was succesfull in ruinning rake db:dump

sudo gem install mysql

rake db:create

the problem i am facing is while running rake db:schema:load

i am getting the following error while running the above command

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails: DROP TABLE `advance_salaries` CASCADE
/home/vh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `_query'
/home/vh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `block in query'
/home/vh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/vh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `query'
```

dont know why i am facing this issue.please help....................!!!!!!

Comment: reply is very urgent for me guys..........so please help..........if anyone knows the solution......

Comment: all my project has stopped working... :/

Comment: Could you add you schema.rb? Did you try just rake db:migrate instead of  schema:load?

Comment: yes....rake db:schema:load..........but shows same error...!!!

Comment: create_table "advance_salaries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "employee_id"
    t.decimal  "advance_amount",    precision: 15, scale: 2
    t.string   "no_of_instalment"
    t.decimal  "instalment_amount", precision: 15, scale: 2
    t.date     "advance_date"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                 null: false
    t.integer  "advance_type_id"
    t.decimal  "interest",          precision: 15, scale: 2
  end

Comment: one more child table.....installments.....

Comment: create_table "instalments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "advance_salary_id"
    t.date     "instalment_date"
    t.decimal  "instalment_amount", precision: 15, scale: 2
    t.datetime "created_at",                                                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                                 null: false
    t.boolean  "is_complete",                                default: false
  end

  add_index "instalments", ["advance_salary_id"], name: "index_instalments_on_advance_salary_id"

Comment: still i am getting same error...........

Answer (score 0):

When you use db:schema:load, rails will clean your db and rebuild schema, and there is exist dependence in your db relation so it bring error.

The detail can reference :

[ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row - Rails 4.2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664061/activerecordstatementinvalid-mysql2error-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent)

Comment: not helping........i was on sqllite database and switched to mysql database and i'm getting this error.Don't know how to solve this issue.......please help.....

Comment: i am able to migrate,only problem while doing rake db:load.

Comment: @puneet pls help....if youkniow the solution.....i am in great proble...whole my application has stopped...........!!!!!

Comment: i have an existing application which is running on sqlite3,so now i want to switch my entire application from sqlite to mysql.I changed all my configurationa nd also was successful in running rake db:migrate.Problem i'm facing while running rake db:schema:load.Dont know my my schema file is not loading.i want to backup all my existing application database from sqlite to mysql.

Comment: this is my new question link...please help.......... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061570/strftime-error-while-switching-my-database-from-sqlite3-to-mysql-in-rails4

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow below command:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

Comment: thanks guys for all your reply.....i am successful in changing my dtabase from sqlite3 to mysql.But now i am getting strtime error in one of my file.The link for the question is...........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061570/strftime-error-while-switching-my-database-from-sqlite3-to-mysql-in-rails4